# Css embed in jsp and how to deploy both css and html in jsp

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, servlets

Hi

Now at time being i am new in java i want to embed css in jsp by using two jsp one for html and other for css same like Dreamweaver i done it neatbeans and second confusion is that how both files deploy for example our jsp for html liey in `webapp/myapp/index.jsp` and where our css file will go? or remain in `webapp/myapp/index.jsp,css.jsp` or what type of extension we give by using css in jsp.thanx for ans.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder named CSS or to your wish under the path `webapp/myapp/CSS` and save your css files inside.

To link a css file to your jsp file , use the following syntax ,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/myapp/CSS/main.css">
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score -1):

You do it like you were usually doing it. You create a file with the css extension and add the link in the jsp file. You can put the css file wherever you want as long as you give the correct path when you link it in the jsp page.
Here you have an example of how you can have you files structure.
And in any of the pages I just add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/newstylesheet.css" type="text/css">
```

[image]

Comment: Be more specific with examples

Comment: @sankrish Sorry, I thought it's specific enough. Edited, hope it's better now